# Sound hotkeys not working after switch to Bluetooth headset

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have laptop with Bluetooth and Bluetooth headphones.
Sound control with Fn+SoundUp/Down(I get notification in GUI and volume level changes).
Also headphones working well.
But some times I got such strange behavior(error) with head set:
I press FN+Volume Up/Down/Mute/Mic mute i get only mate-notification and no sound changes.
[image]

If i turnoff headset same key can control laptop speakers and 3.5mm jack headphones with Fn keys.

How can i fix volume control with hotkeys?

**UPD**
I found a workaround.
If i open sound settings from tray and in tab `Output` switch output to integrated audio and then back to Bluetooth Headphones I'm able to control audio with Fn-keys.
So is it a bug? That i need to report to ubuntu or wrong configuration on my side?

System:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 Mate
- Dell Latitude 5480
- Headphones Philips SHB7250
- pulseaudio
- Pavucontrol